# Error pasting data from other workbook|worksheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an error when pasting the data into the new workbook, the workbook where i'm pasting the data has a header and it's pasting it from there.
The first edit didn't have the wbCopyFrom, wsCopyFrom, wbCopyTo, wsCopyTo set because when i first tried the macro it didn't take it in consideration and just pasted the data to the workbook i'm refering to

```
Sub RechazosOnline()
Dim rsh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
Dim wbCopyFrom As Workbook, wsCopyFrom As Worksheet

Set wb = Workbooks("2. Detalle_Transacciones_pendientes_rechazadas_MDM_27Ene20.xlsx")
Set wbCopyFrom = Workbooks("1. ReporteGeneral_TransaccionesDiariasMDM_20200115")
Set wsCopyFrom = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets("Detalle")
wsCopyFrom.Range("A2:I" & wsCopyFrom.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).Copy

For Each rsh In wb.Sheets
         rsh.Range("A2:I" & rsh.Range("A" & rsh.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     Next
End Sub
```

In the second edit i setted wbCopyFrom, wsCopyFrom, wbCopyTo, wsCopyTo but had the same result

```
Sub RechazosOnline()
    * Im pasting the same data into the two sheets of the workbook, so rsh is generic
    Dim rsh As Worksheet 
    Dim wbCopyFrom As Workbook, wsCopyFrom As Worksheet, wbCopyTo As Workbook

    Set wbCopyTo = Workbooks("2. Detalle_Transacciones_pendientes_rechazadas_MDM_27Ene20.xlsx")
    Set wbCopyFrom = Workbooks("1. ReporteGeneral_TransaccionesDiariasMDM_20200115")
    Set wsCopyFrom = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets("Detalle")
    wsCopyFrom.Range("A2:I" & wsCopyFrom.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).Copy

    For Each rsh In wbCopyTo.Sheets
             rsh.Range("A2:I" & rsh.Range("A" & rsh.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
         Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the issue here?

Comment: When i'm pasting the data, it doesn't paste it from A2:Down, it pastes it from the header downwards @urdearboy, the header is replaced with the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the issue just that the data is being pasted over the header? If so, just `Offset` the paste row by one.

```
rsh.Range("A2:I" & rsh.Range("A" & rsh.Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

---

I believe this is a little cleaner

```
Dim LR as Long

For Each rsh In wbCopyTo.Sheets
    LR = rsh.Range("A" & rsh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    rsh.Range("A" & LR).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next rsh
```